# How to apply patch in specific file - git

Tags: git

I generated a patch from the `master` branch and would like to apply it to a secondary branch but the error, I believe, happens because it was created by the `master` branch patch:

```
error: patch failed: src/projects/file.py:16
error: src/projects/file.py: patch does not apply
```

Comment: What not use `git cherry-pick -1 <sha>` from master to your current branch. I assume you got a conflict, but cherry-picking will put you into a state where you can actually resolve conflicts manually.

Comment: Or you want to apply a cherry-pick from another branch only for one particular file, ignoring changes in other files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`git apply docs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply)

For atomicity, git apply by default fails the whole patch and does not touch the working tree when some of the hunks do not apply.

You can make use of `--reject` option to apply the parts of the patch that are applicable, and leave the rejected hunks in corresponding `*.rej` files.

Also When applying a patch, ignore changes in whitespace in context lines if necessary. Context lines will preserve their whitespace, and they will not undergo whitespace fixing regardless of the value of the --whitespace option.

You can run patch with the following command then

```
git apply --reject --ignore-space-change file.path
```